# Python module vs class

Tags: python, class, module

Trying to see if I understand the differences. If I wanted to make a bunch of different cars then I would make a Car class because I need multiple, different instances. If I wanted to use an add, subtract, etc, function then I should make a module since I don't need multiple instances of a calculator I only need to use the functions inside. Is that accurate? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you were to make an add, subtract, multiply or divide function it is better not being a class.

And yes, you are right with the car class.

I don't see how this is `Python` related.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only language I know that uses modules is Python.

Comment: There's quite a few. [Link to wikipedia on modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)

Comment: I knew that other languages break up code into separate files. I just didn't know if there was something special about a "module" vs a class besides what I stated.